# How to get all selected ids at once ? PHP/MySQL question

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have MySQL table called `Files` which has `file_id` column and `file_type` column (and also other columns that are not relevant to the question).

I would like to get all `file_id`s of all picture files (i.e. `file_type='picture'`).

I do the query like this:

```
$pictures_query = mysql_query("SELECT file_id FROM Files WHERE file_type='picture')
```

and now the question is: how would I put all picture `file_id`s into an array ?

I thought to do this like that:

```
$pictures_ids = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($pictures_query)) {
    $pictures_ids[] = $row[0];
}
```

Does the loop really necessary, or there is a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) with [`explode`](http://www.php.net/explode) to avoid looping:

```
$pictures_query = mysql_query("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(file_id) FROM Files WHERE file_type='picture'");

$file_ids = explode(',', mysql_result($pictures_query, 0));
```

Comment: Hey, nice! +1. With millions of records, it is going to be more resource intensive to do this way than walking through a loop. In most cases, though, it won't matter.

Comment: @Pekka, true, this is far from optimal and I'd rather use looping in any case, but it's possible anyways. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I'll stay with the loop solution :)

Answer (score 2):

The loop is necessary as long as you don't use any other functionality that hides that loop from you like `Doctrine` does by hydration or `MYSQLI` does with it's iterator like `next_result()` function or its `fetch_all function()`.

Answer (score 1):

The loop is in fact necessary. (Update: except if you use `GROUP_CONCAT` as shown by Tatu).

PDO has a [`fetch_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) method, but the `mysql_*` functions don't.